# Comparing Sheet's Cell Data is not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '//this macro checks whether two sheet's data is correspondent.
    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    For i2 = 1 To i2 = 31
        For i1 = 1 To i1 = 27
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox1.Value).Cells(i1, i2).Value <> _
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox2.Value).Cells(i1, i2).Value Then
                MsgBox "Value of " & i1 & "rows " & i2 & "column : " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
                & UserForm2.TextBox1.Value & " sheets : " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox1.Value).Cells(i1, i2).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
                & UserForm2.TextBox2.Value & " sheets :  : " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox2.Value).Cells(i1, i2).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "End"
End Sub
```

Above is My Code.

Its function is Simple.

It receives two sheet's name from UserForm TextBox

And Check whether two sheets has same content

But, it don't work, even with no error message.

I pressed the button but it didnt response.

Just "End" Message pops up.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for you answer in advance.

Comment: Either translate those comments and variable names to English or get rid of them. Few people will know Korean (?) but everybody will understand English.

Comment: This is an English-based site.  I even tried translating it in Google Translate but since it adds spaces in strange places it's impossible to tell where your issue is.  For example, I assume one of the lines doesn't say `Dim Loop Counter 2 As Integer For Loop Statement Counter 2 = 1 To Loop Statement Counter 2 = 3`, or pasting it into North American (non-unicode) VBE gives `Dim ??????2 As Integer For ??????2 = 1 To ??????2 = 31 For ??????1 = 1 To ??????1 = 27` ... not very helpful, sorry

Comment: I think it is easy to understand even if it is wrote in korean,(because variables name is doesnt matter like this simple code) but I didnt expect it displayed like "???" "???", Sorry,

Comment: Now I'm editing my code from korean to english, please don't give minus score to my question, sorry

Comment: For i2 = 1 To i2 = 31 you can simply put as  For i2 = 1 To 31

Comment: And put ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox1.Value) into a variable aswell as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.TextBox2.Value) so as to make your loops more efficient (the values are known and do not change during the loop so you don't need to keep retrieving them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more by way of an extended comment.

See the following as a re-write (I have not tested) but shows how you can use variables to store the values and therefore be more efficient. I suggest you step through the code checking the values of each of the variables (in the locals window or with watches) and make sure they are as you expect. Run some cases you expect to see fail and insert break on change in values for your watch values perhaps? References here for [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '//this macro checks whether two sheet's data is correspondent.
    Dim i1 As Long
    Dim i2 As Long

    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String

    text1 = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
    text2 = UserForm2.TextBox2.Value

    Dim testSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim testSheet2 As Worksheet

    testSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(text1)
    testValue2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(text2)

    For i2 = 1 To 31

        For i1 = 1 To 27

            If testSheet1.Cells(i1, i2).Value <> testSheet2.Cells(i1, i2).Value Then

                MsgBox "Value of " & i1 & "rows " & i2 & "column : " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
                & text1 & " sheets : " & testSheet1.Cells(i1, i2).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
                & text2 & " sheets :  : " & testSheet2.Cells(i1, i2).Value

            End If

        Next i1

    Next i2

    MsgBox "End"

End Sub
```